# Minimality properties of James' space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am interested in the following question about James' quasi-reflexive Banach space $\mathcal{J}$:

> Does there exists a non-Hilbertian subspace $X$ of $\mathcal{J}$ such that $X$ isomorphically embeds into every non-Hilbertian subspace of itself?

Here, by "subspace" I mean "closed, infinite-dimensional vector subspace", and by "Hilbertian" I mean "isomorphic to $\ell_2$".

I vaguely recall having found, one year ago, a paper proving that the answer to this question was no, or at least giving a similar/partial result suggesting that the answer should be no. Problem is, I don't manage to find this paper again, I don't even remember who were the authors and what was the exact result they proved. Do some of you recall having seen something like that?

Comment: It's a pitty that the ask-johnson-tag does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

A weaker `block version' is true for the conditional spreading basis (the summing basis) of $\mathcal{J}$: Every seminormalized block basis of the spreading basis has a subsequence either equivalent to an unconditional basis ($\ell_2$) or a convex block sequence equivalent to the basis itself. The result holds in general in spaces with a convex block homogeneous conditional spreading basis. See the section 5 of the following paper

> [A study of conditional spreading sequences
>   Spiros A. Argyros, Pavlos Motakis, Bünyamin Sari](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04443)

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: As you can see, the ask-johnson-tag is no longer needed on MO. Good riddance!

Comment: @Bunyamin Sari: In this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041285?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents, the authors prove that James' space has uncountably many pairwise nonequivalent unconditional basic sequences. This contradicts your claim that the only one is $\ell_2$.

Actually, $\mathcal{J}$ itself cannot have the property I'm asking about: the same paper shows it has non-Hilbertian reflexive subspaces, hence it cannot isomorphically embed into these subspaces.

Comment: I agree that the result I quoted doesn't answer your question, sorry I was too quick. I edited the answer. This doesn't contradict the results you quoted either because it involves block subspaces of the conditional basis.

Comment: We clearly very much still need the ask-johnson-tag!

Comment: Let $X:=\left(\sum_n \oplus E_n \right)_2$ with $d_n(X):=\sup d(E,\ell_2^n)\to\infty$. Is there $Y:=\left(\sum_n \oplus F_n \right)_2\subset X$ so that $d_n(Y)\to \infty$ in much slower pace (so that $X$ doesn't embed into $Y$). This is surely true, and would answer the OP's question in negative.

Comment: You don't need that much, Bunyamin, to give a negative to answer the OP's question. Given $a_n \uparrow \infty$, build a space $Y$ of the form $(\sum_n \ell_{p_n}^{m_n})_2$ so that $m_n^{|1/p_n -1/2|}\to \infty$ but $a_n/(m_n^{|1/p_n -1/2|})\to \infty$ with $p_n\downarrow 2$.  Do this by induction so that a  $m_1 + \dots m_n$ is much smaller than $m_{n+1}$ and so that $m_n$ dimensional subspaces of $L_{p_{n+1}}$ are $2$-isomorphic to Hilbert spaces (which is the same as $m_n^{|1/p_{n+1} -1/2|} \le 2$). This is easy even if it is a pain to write down the details.

Comment: Bill, how do you make sure such spaces $\left(\sum_n \ell_{p_n}^{m_n}\right)_2$ embed into an arbitrary non-Hilbertian subspace of $\mathcal J$.

Comment: Given any non Hilbertian subspace of James' space, you construct a space of that form into which the subspace does not embed, which gives a negative answer to the OP's question. Not every non Hilbertian subspace of James' space contains such a space.  Conceivably every non Hilbertian subspace of James' space contains an a non Hilbertian $\ell_2$ sum of finite dimensional $\ell_{p_n}$ spaces (where the $p_n$ can be on either side of $2$), but I doubt it.

Comment: I think the question asks something harder: if every non-Hibertian subspace $X$ embeds into a non-Hilbertian subspace of $X$ itself.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question repeatedly. Thanks.