# A minimality problem for a class of Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following question is related to the previous question [Minimality properties of James' space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351842/minimality-properties-of-james-space); I post it as a new question since the system does not allow me to add a comment.

**Question**  Consider the following class of non-Hilbertian spaces:
    $X_{p,2}=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \oplus\ell^p_n)_2$, $1\le p\le \infty$, $p\neq 2$.
 Is it true that the only infinite dimensional Banach space that is isomorphically embedded into anyone of them is the Hilbert space?

Notice that all these spaces are subspaces of the space $\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: For somebody outside this community: $\ell^p_n$ means the $n$-dimensional $\ell^p$? $(\Sigma\cdots)_2$ means the $\ell^2$-sum? Certainly "is the Hilbert space" means "is isomorphic to a Hilbert space".

Comment: @YCor Yes to all.

Comment: How do you know these spaces are subspaces of $\mathcal{J}$?  I suppose its sufficient to prove the case $p=\infty$, whence the remaining cases follow due to the fact that all finite-dimensional spaces embed almost isometrically into $\ell_\infty^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @Ben W The standard basis of $\mathcal J$ is skipped Hilbertian so whenever you have finite dimensional spaces with a gap in between their supports, they add in $\ell_2$ sense.

Comment: @BunyaminSari Right but can you really find $\ell_\infty^n$ uniformly in $\mathcal{J}$ in the first place?

Comment: @Ben W Yes, $c_0$ is finitely representable in $\mathcal J$. I don't have access to references now though.

Comment: @BunyaminSari Oh that's cool.  I can find a reference myself if need be, now that I know what to look for.  Ty : )

Comment: That James' space fails cotype was proved by James himself in the 1970s IIRC.

Comment: Here is a [reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=GQJVVtDwx5wC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=c_0+finitely+representable+in+james+space&source=bl&ots=qdemHyJzW4&sig=ACfU3U28fZMXIO4vkF6PlFRIarpyIzfptA&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIpZ-uhMPnAhUKTawKHZ3vAIUQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=c_0%20finitely%20representable%20in%20james%20space&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

I think such a space has type 2 and cotype 2 so by Kwapien's theorem it is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: I would, then, be interested in the answer to the original question when we restrict our attention to $p>2$.

Comment: Yes; you only need embedding for one $\infty>p>2$ and one $p<2$ to apply Kwapien's theorem.  If you have embedding for all $p>2$ and uniform control on the isomorphism constants, then again you get a positive answer (use the fact that any $n$ dimensional subspace of $L_p$ is $n^{|1/p-1/2|}$ isomorphic to $\ell_p^n$).

Comment: OTOH, if $X$ embeds into $X_{p,2}$ for all $p<2$, then $X$ need not be isomorphic to a Hilbert space. Take $p_n \uparrow 2$ and $m_n \to \infty$. Then $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell_{p_n}^{m_n})_2$ embeds into $X_{p,2}$ for all $p<2$ but is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space if $m_n \to \infty$ sufficiently quickly.

Comment: Proposition 21.6 and Remark 2 following In Tomczak-Jaegermann's book "Banach-Mazur Distances..." yield that for for all $2<s<p<\infty$, $\ell_s$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_2(\ell_p)$, with uniformly bounded isomorphism constant for $s<(2+p)/2$. It follows  that if $s_n\downarrow2$ and $m_n \to \infty$ quickly, then $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell_{s_n}^{m_n})_2$ embeds into $X_{p,2}$ for all $p>2$ but is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the OP's question?  It sounded like he was asking whether every Banach space is a Hilbert space that embeds isomorphically into $(\oplus\ell_p^n)_{\ell_2}$, $p\in[1,2)\cup(2,\infty]$.  But the space itself is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space, so the answer is no.

Comment: @Ben W Bill is answering the natural follow up question of what happens if you restrict to $p<2$ and $p>2$.